# Why does the active homepage sometimes show questions that haven't been bumped in a long time?

Tags: bug, recent-activity, homepage, caching

Just now I saw these old, inactive questions at the top of the ["active" homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4PA74.png) here on MSE:

[image: Top of list here on MSE showing questions from December 2023]

At the bottom are extremely old and dormant posts ("Modified 2 years, 6 months ago", so old the mobile apps are recommended as part of the answer):

[image: modified June 2021]

Refreshing always fixes this, which I say because I've seen this several times before. It may not be high priority but I do find it disorienting.

Comment: Yup getting this too sometimes, but since refresh "fix" it, didn't report.