# Why is “top questions” on mobile view broken for meta.stackexchange.com?

Tags: support, bug, homepage

I navigated to “meta.stackexchange.com”, and it defaulted to “Top Questions”, but no questions showed up on the mobile view. Is this feature broken?[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's not what I see in Edge on my iPhone ([home](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pn8Zm.jpg) and [all questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBOKQ.jpg)). Perhaps there's some (inadvertent, possibly in a title or excerpt) markup that your browser objects to? Maybe one that only shows in that view because it is older but had activity recently? (Don't judge my battery level - I have an excuse.)

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/395899/why-does-the-active-homepage-sometimes-show-questions-that-havent-been-bumped-i). I don't think it's related to mobile, sometimes the server side cache holding the questions list get messed up, SE needs to check that. /cc @AaronBertrand

Comment: Wait, I assume it was OK after you reloaded? If it's consistent then it's not related.

Comment: @Shadow Well, I don't _personally_ know a whole lot about server-side caching, either in general or specific to our config. But if it was a pervasive issue, wouldn't we all see it on every page load, and on all devices, not just mobile? If it's isolated to a single web server, surely more than just George would be unlucky to hit that one.

Comment: A refresh corrected the issue.